# Submit Flink Job on Yarn cluster to restores its state from it's last savepoint

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am running these Flink job in a Yarn cluster. When the flink job fails or I restart it I want the Flink job to use the savepoint that was created before it restarted. 
How do can restart the Flink job with this savepoint. I am using Flink 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resume from a savepoint you have to call `bin/flink run -s :savepointPath [:runArgs]` where `runArgs` contains the job jar.

Comment: This works well if I am doing it directly via CLI. I am using a Yarn Client to submit the job.